# Reading and merging multiple data files

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I've recently started teaching myself Python but have no prior programming experience or formal training. I've successfully created a program that outputs what I wanted it to output, but I'm looking for guidance on design/efficiency. Is there an overall design that would have been more efficient? Any pieces of code that should be re-written to be more stylistically correct? I purposely wrote this program without utilizing a database, but my next goal is to re-write the program to use a database instead of dictionaries.

The goal of this program is to read in 3 files that have a common key (custID). A customer can have multiple orders, but only one email/customer record. File layouts:

```
names.txt: custID|firstName|lastName|address1|address2|city|state|zip
emails.txt: custID|email
orders.txt: orderID|orderDate|channel|orderAmt|custID
```

Then, output a file with each order appearing on a new line:

```
output.txt: custID|firstName|lastName|city|state|email|orderDate|orderAmount
```

Program:

```
import re
import os

cust_info = {}
cust_emails = {}
cust_orders = {}
cust_join = {}

#Read Customer file with layout: 
#custID|firstName|lastName|address1|address2|city|state|zip
def read_cust_file():
    with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:          
        for line in f:
            split_line = re.sub("\s\s+", '|', line).strip().split('|')
            cust_info[int(split_line[0])] = "|".join(split_line[1:])
    return cust_info


#Read Email file with layout: custID|email
def read_email_file():           
    with open('emails.txt', 'r') as g:          
        for line in g:
            split_line = re.sub("\s\s+", '|', line).strip().split('|')
            cust_emails[int(split_line[0])] = "|".join(split_line[1:])
    return cust_emails


#Read Order file with layout: orderID|orderDate|channel|orderAmt|custID
#There can be multiple orders per custID
def read_order_file():        
    with open('orders.txt', 'r') as f:          
        for line in f:
            split_line = re.sub("\s\s+", '|', line).strip().split('|')
            try:
                cust_orders.setdefault(int(split_line[4]),[]).append("|".join(
                    split_line[0:4]))        
            except KeyError:
                pass
    return cust_orders


#Join names, emails, and orders together on custID (dict key)
def join_orders():

    for key in set(list(cust_info) + list(cust_emails) + list(cust_orders)):
        try:
            cust_join.setdefault(key,[]).append(cust_info[key])        
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            cust_join.setdefault(key,[]).append(cust_emails[key])          
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            cust_join.setdefault(key,[]).append(cust_orders[key])          
        except KeyError:
            pass

    return cust_join


#Format output layout:
#custID|firstName|lastName|city|state|email|orderDate|orderAmount
#Each order will be on a separate line, even if a cust made more than 1 order.
def write_output():
    output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
    for k, v in cust_join.items():
        if len(v) == 3:
            for item in v[2]:
                split_cust = v[0].split('|')
                split_item = item.split('|')
                output_file.write("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n" % (
                    k, split_cust[0], split_cust[1], split_cust[4], 
                    split_cust[5], v[1], split_item[1], split_item[3]))
    output_file.truncate(output_file.tell() - len(os.linesep))
    output_file.close()




def main():

    read_cust_file()
    read_email_file()
    read_order_file()
    join_orders()
    write_output()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I really appreciate any advice you all can give!

Answer (score 3):

Looks not too bad, it's readable enough.  The use of `with` is good (except for `writeOutput`, where it's not used for some reason) and the code is split into separate functions by functionality.  That said:

### Stylistic

- You should read and follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (naming of globals, functions,
  variables, whitespace, no need for semicolons).
- You don't need those globals, just return values from your functions.
- Maybe use docstrings instead of comments if you're describing the
  functionality of a function.
- Create more functions for common code.  If you copy and paste
  something is wrong (usually).  That applies to all the reader functions, as they share the line splitting and accumulation code.
- The `try/except` blocks in `joinOrders` aren't good.  Exceptions
  aren't for control flow (usually) and you're better off using a
  different approach for better understanding (where could the exception
  be raised from) and maintainability (if you move the block or change
  things, does the exception still only apply to the part you originally
  wanted too, etc.)

## Design

- You might be better off using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module with custom separators
  to read the files.  Even as a beginner it's a good idea to use
  libraries to make your life easier.
- The double splitting in the read functions looks unnecessary, but I'm
  not quite sure.
- Why the weird `truncate`?  It's normal for text files to end with a
  newline.
- Unless you're not concerned about speed the list concatenation in
  `joinOrders` isn't the best idea.  Creating the set from `custInfo`,
  then calling `update` on the set would be better to avoid unnecessary
  allocations for the list.
- Use `iter*` on dictionaries, lists, etc. for efficiency if you only iterate over the elements.  Here that would be `iteritems` instead of `items`.

Overall the split into input and output makes sense and I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency at this point (unless you're processing huge amounts of data that is).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is certainly on the right track, but could use some improvements.

---

PEP8, Python's official style guide, says the naming structure for [functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) as:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

So, `readCustFile` and the other functions named like `fooBarBar`, would be better off like `for_bar_bar`.

PEP8, also recommends `foo_bar` for the variable naming structure.

You should have a space after a comma in a list `','` into `', '`

---

Your `try`, `except` loop is really lacking in effiency, you ought to improve that:

> ```
>     try:
>         custJoin.setdefault(key,[]).append(custInfo[key])        
>     except KeyError:
>         pass
>
>     try:
>         custJoin.setdefault(key,[]).append(custEmails[key])          
>     except KeyError:
>         pass
>
>     try:
>         custJoin.setdefault(key,[]).append(custOrders[key])          
>     except KeyError:
>         pass
> ```

---

Your code really feels overly complicated, like the task it's achieving could be completed with a reworked style of procedure.